# Using bijective correspondence between functions from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow\{0,1\}$ and power set of $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology

I am having some confusion with the notion of interpreting the topological space $2^\mathbb{R}$ the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ as equivalent to the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.The book I am using says to interpret each function as associated with the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ containing the point $a \in \mathbb{R}$ if $f(a)=1$ and not containing $a$ if $f(a)=0$. For some reason I am then interpreting the space $2^ \mathbb{R}$ with the product topology to be equivalent with the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Is this correct?

For example I am looking at the following question:In the product space $2^\mathbb{R}$, what is the closure of the set $Z$ consisting of all elements of $2^\mathbb{R}$ that are $0$ on every rational coordinate but may be $0$ or $1$ on any irrational coordinate?Equivalently, thinking of $2^\mathbb{R}$ as subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ what is the closure of the set $Z$ consisting of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that do not contain any rational?

An answer that I first came up with was that the closure of $Z$ should be $Z$ itself, because every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ in the discrete topology is closed and therefore equal to its closure. However, I know that the problem is not that trivial. Now that I think about this, is my interpretation the notion that the functions themselves are the elements of the product topology on $2^\mathbb{R}$, not the topological space? Instead should I think about the product topology?

For any point $x$ in $2^\mathbb{R}$ and open set containing $x$, I know that there is a basis element of $2^\mathbb{R}$ with all but finitely many factors equal to $\{0,1\}$ containing $x$.Then should this basis element intersect a point in $Z$, necessarily?

I would appreciate if someone could clear up my confusion on interpreting the set $\mathbb{R}$ as equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology, and lead me in the right direction in solving this problem.

Comment: It's not precisely an answer to your question, but does https://math.stackexchange.com/a/470439/259262 give you enough?

Comment: Note that if you are putting a topology on $2^{\mathbb{R}}$, and $2^{\mathbb{R}}$ is equivalent to the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then you are not putting a topology on $\mathbb{R}$, you are putting a topology on the **power set** of $\mathbb{R}$. So it doesn’t make sense to say that you are getting “the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$”: it’s the wrong space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb R}$ the reals are just an index set, or the domain for the set of functions. We're not implying or putting any topology on it, we're just discussing the set of *all* functions on $\Bbb R$ with codomain $\{0,1\}$. If we have such a function $f$  we "identify" it with the subset $A=f^{-1}[\{1\}$ of $\Bbb R$. This way, we've "encoded" all subsets with a unique function and every such function encodes a subset. The set $\{0,1\}$ *does* have the discrete topology, but then the product topology on $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb R}$ is very far from discrete; it has no isolated points at all.

Let $A \subseteq \{0,1\}^{\Bbb R}$ be all functions such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in \Bbb Q$, which indeed corresponds to all subsets of the reals that contain no rational under the aforementioned correspondence.

My claim is that this set is closed: Let $g \notin A$. This means that $g(q)=1$ for some $q \in \Bbb Q$. But then $\pi_q^{-1}[\{1\}]$ is subbasic open in $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb R}$, contains $g$ and is disjoint from $A$, as all members in it by definition also have value $1$ at $q$ (i.e. contain $q$) and so do contain a rational. We can see the basic open sets in this space (when we view them as subsets of $\Bbb R$ as "contain-and-miss" sets: A basic set is of the form (own notation here) $[F;G]:= \{A \subseteq \Bbb R: F \subseteq A; A \cap G = \emptyset\}$ where $F,G \subseteq \Bbb R$ are finite. (In the above proof I used $[\{q\}; \emptyset]$, really). This fits into a more general pattern of other topologies on spaces of subsets (like the Vietoris topology, the Pixley-Roy topology and many others).